# GPO's; Edge sync with automatic login using Domain\username instead of username@domain.com

Tags: azure, synchronization, microsoft-edge

I am trying to set up Edge sync for domain joined users. They authenticate on our terminal server using the Domain\Username format. The sign in works in edge, but the synchronisation refuses. Whenever i use the username@domain.com format it will both sign and and synchronise.

I assume this has something to do with the way Azure only recognising the UPN format.

Is there any way to either make Edge log users in using the UPN format or Azure recognizing/map the domain\username accounts?

Answer (score 1):

When you login to edge you are using an AAD account, not an AD one. AAD only supports logging in through a UPN (unless you are using federation). The legacy pre-2000 login is not synced to AAD and it does not support it's use.

Comment: Im able to log into the terminal servers using both an AD and AAD account. they are both available since our dc is syncing to our azure ad in preparation of a migration. Is there a way to make the environment use the AAD account or prioritise the AAD account?

Comment: Unless your using Server 2019 with AAD Domain join, you are not logging into your Terminal servers using an AAD account, you are using an AD account, but AD supports login with either UPN or legacy, UPN's were introduced with Active Directory.